# How to name results of foreach loop by including errorhandling in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, foreach, parallel-processing

How to detect which iteration failed in `foreach` loop? The `.errorhandling = "remove"` helps run the code successfully but `.final` causes an error as it cannot match the names. How to handle such situations?

```
  res <- foreach(i=names(train_test_split), 
                 .multicombine = TRUE,
                 .verbose = TRUE,
                 .errorhandling = "remove",
                 .packages = c("caret", "MLmetrics"),
                 .final = function(x){setNames(x, names(train_test_split))},
                 .export = c("train_rf_model", "train_glmnet_model", "train_svmRadial_model", "train_nb_model")) %dopar% {}
```

Here the `res` is a list. If the code executes successfully, the names come out correctly but if one of the iterations fails, the execution stops.

Answer (score 0):

I've not found a way of doing what you want *within* your `%dopar%` call, but here's a way of working things out post-hoc.

```
library(foreach)
library(tidyverse)

rv <- foreach(
  i=1:3, 
  .multicombine = TRUE,
  .verbose = TRUE,
  .errorhandling = "remove"
) %dopar% {
  tryCatch({
    if (i == 2) stop("i == 2 is an error!")
    data.frame(Iteration = i, X = runif(3))
  },
  error = function(cond) {
    return(message(cond))
  })
}

rv
[[1]]
  Iteration          X
1         1 0.06072057
2         1 0.94772694
3         1 0.72059627

[[2]]
  Iteration         X
1         3 0.1422943
2         3 0.5492847
3         3 0.9540912
```

So we have an error in iteration 2 and a mismatch between the loop index passed to `%dopar%` and the indices of the returned `list`.  Note that I've added a column to my result `data.frame` that defines the iteration number.

So now it's easy to check if I've got all the indices I expect:

```
rv %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  distinct(Iteration) %>% 
  pull(Iteration) %>% 
  setdiff(1:3, .)
[1] 2
```

And you can post-process on the basis of this as you see fit.